# Wrapping bash command that is a string

Tags: bash, shell

So I have this bash command:

```
sqlite3 ${SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH}  "CREATE TABLE suman_run_info (run_id INTEGER, suman_id INTEGER, suite_id INTEGER, test_id INTEGER,
 name TEXT, value TEXT);" >> ${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}
```

I want to wrap it manually in my editor. However since it's mostly a string, I can't seem to wrap it with the \ character.

A.k.a, this is not really going to work, tmk:

```
sqlite3 ${SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH}  "CREATE TABLE suman_run_info \ (run_id INTEGER, suman_id INTEGER, suite_id INTEGER, test_id INTEGER,
 name TEXT, value TEXT);" >> ${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}
```

How can I wrap this bash command so that it fits within 100 columns or whatever?

I am looking for something like this:

```
sqlite3 ${SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH}  "CREATE TABLE suman_run_info (run_id INTEGER, 
     suman_id INTEGER, suite_id INTEGER, test_id INTEGER,
     name TEXT, value TEXT);" >> ${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}
```

I have read that adjacent strings should auto-concat, so maybe this works?

```
   sqlite3 ${SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH}  "CREATE TABLE suman_run_info" 
   "(run_id INTEGER, suman_id INTEGER, suite_id INTEGER, test_id INTEGER,"
     "name TEXT, value TEXT);" >> ${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah sure np, coming right up

Comment: As an aside -- POSIX specifies all-caps names for variables with meaning to the OS or shell, and reserves names with lower-case characters for application use, guaranteeing that lower-case names won't conflict with reserved words meaningful to the OS or shell. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable with a name that conflicts with an existing environment variable will overwrite the latter.

Comment: Your last example maybe with a slash at the end?

Comment: Re: "adjacent strings auto-concat" -- presumably that's in reference to `'foo'"bar"baz`, but that's not actually two (or three) adjacent strings at all; it's one string composed with characters quoted in three different styles.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the tip re: all-caps names...I might just pre-pend a lowercase char in front of all my current names so SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH -> sSUMAN_DATABASE_PATH or whatever. that should work

Answer (score 5):

You don't need anything, in this case at least; SQL can handle newlines in the command without a problem. This should work just fine:

```
sqlite3 "${SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH}"  "CREATE TABLE suman_run_info
  (run_id INTEGER, 
   suman_id INTEGER,
   suite_id INTEGER,
   test_id INTEGER,
   name TEXT,
   value TEXT
  );" >> "${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}"
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to have **nothing** after the backslash:

```
sqlite3 ${SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH}  "CREATE TABLE suman_run_info \
    (run_id INTEGER, suman_id INTEGER, suite_id INTEGER, \
    test_id INTEGER, name TEXT, value TEXT);" >> ${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}
```

Or, even better (see comments here below):

```
 sqlite3 "${SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH}"  "CREATE TABLE suman_run_info \
    (run_id INTEGER, suman_id INTEGER, suite_id INTEGER, \
    test_id INTEGER, name TEXT, value TEXT);" >> "${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}"
```

Comment: Should quote the expansion of `$SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH` and `$SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH` -- otherwise they're vulnerable to splitting on characters in IFS (or, by default, whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [`HEREDOC`s](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
sqlite3 ${SUMAN_DATABASE_PATH} <<EOF  >> ${SUMAN_DEBUG_LOG_PATH}
CREATE TABLE suman_run_info
  (run_id INTEGER, 
   suman_id INTEGER,
   suite_id INTEGER,
   test_id INTEGER,
   name TEXT,
   value TEXT);
EOF
```

Comment: huh but would this work multiple times in the same file? I think not right? idk

Comment: @AlexanderMills, without knowing your specific use-case, I would guess that a HEREDOC would work just as well as a string literal.

Comment: I thought you could only use one HEREDOC per file

Comment: @AlexanderMills, my experience suggests otherwise.

Comment: huh, the semantics of EOF (end of file) ... I always assumed you could only have one